# Exclude log entries based on channel and level from Symfony logging

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, monolog

My Current configuration:

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        target_main:
            type:         fingers_crossed
            action_level: debug
            handler: file_log
            channels: ['!security' '!request']
        file_log:
            type: rotating_file
            path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level: debug
            max_files: 2
```

Now request channel is completely excluded from file_log handler. I need to exclude **only action_level - debug** from channel request and not request channel totally. Is it possible with symfony monolog configuration and if yes how?

Comment: Why do you need the `action_level` as `debug` here?